# Class Instantiation Making code more readable

Tags: c#, class, code-readability

The code I'm posting below works and does exactly what I expect it to do.  My question is whether I'm actually USING the class in the correct way?  Should it be structured differently?  My main concern is around the creation of the datatable and the fact that I'm adding columns to it in a method.

I had thought of creating a different class for the datatable structure, but since all tables I build will have different column names, number of columns, I don't think that makes sense.

What I'm planning to do with this going forwards is create classes for LINQ sql queries.  Each class will contain its unique linq code and the only thing that all the classes will return is a datatable.  These tables then go through my error checking and comparison processes.  But thats not part of this question.

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace classquery {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Define InputString
            string[] input = { "John", "Mac", "Yes", "No" };

            //Instantiate Class
            DataTable Player = new DataTable();
            Player one = new Player();            
            one.Main();
            one.buildtable(input);
            Player = one.retsetOne;

            //Pass result to DataGridView
            dataGridViewresult.DataSource = Player;
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        //Define Datatable
        private DataTable playerTable = new DataTable();

        //Add DataRow to DataTable
        public void buildtable(string[] strings)
        {
            DataRow row = playerTable.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = strings[0];
            row["Surname"] = strings[1];
            row["Singles"] = strings[2];
            row["Doubles"] = strings[3];
            playerTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //Return DataTable to Main Function
        public DataTable retsetOne
        {
            get { return playerTable; }
        }

        //Build DataTable Columns?
        public void Main()
        {
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Surname");
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Singles");
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Doubles");

        }
    } }
```

Comment: Why are your `using` declarations all on one line?

Comment: Probably belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Anyway, why roll this on your own instead of using EF?

Comment: The obvious question regarding your design is, "Why?" Both Linq-to-SQL and EF provide access to your information in a statically-typed and composable way. What benefits are you hoping to derive from the above design?

Comment: Marcello, just the way it was pasted in.  What do you mean "Why?"  I will move it to Code Review.